# OpenGl/Glut: Draw arc/semi cycle giving first, second, third points and segments

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, linear-algebra, trigonometry

After much deliberation and wandering into the unknown I make request to you: How to draw arc or semi-cyrcle in OpenGL or GLUT giving:

- p1=(x1,y1) be the first point
- p2=(x2,y2) the second point of the half-circle arc,
- p3=(x3,y3) be the previous point preceding the first point.

**EDIT**

Mathematic solve problem is [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907584/how-to-draw-polyline-arc-half-part-of-circle-using-pixel-draw-giving-mouse-loc/1907641?noredirect=1#comment3917200_1907641).

Answer (score 3):

In your for loop you're incrementing your loop variable `i` by 1 with each iteration. Yet your calculation of curve parameter `t` does not take the number of steps into account. I'm kind of reluctant to give you the full solution, but here's a hint: You should divide by `segments` somewhere. Also `segments` likely is an integer, too, so you'll have to cast to `float` or `double`

Now before you start spraying your code with `…/(float)segments` **think!**

I want to you *understand* what you're doing there.

Answer (score 2):

In some Compilers (that I useed) your source-line:

`float t = (PI * i) / 2;`

will result in an integer. Maybe, this is a problem of your rendered lines.

Try to force the compiler to use floats:

`float t = (PI * (float)i) / 2.0f;`

...just to be sure, that your "t" will have decimal-places.